# How to obtain verification for a set of Python scripts?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-cloud-console

I have written a set of Python scripts to access Google Drive on my behalf, to upload/download files and share them.  I use this to distribute and retrieve homework in a class.

My "app" is unverified by Google, and it's not clear how to have it verified: it is not a web app, nor will it be published, so it does not have a home page, nor terms of service, nor anything like that.  It is just a set of Python files that I run to access my Google Drive on my behalf.  I am going to be its only user.  Still, I get throttled in terms of file uploads and shares.

Does anyone know how to get "verified" an app that consists just of a set of Python (or other language) scripts, but is not really published/available on the web anywhere?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: [OAuth API Verification FAQ](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en)?

Comment: What `certain restrictions` are you talking? Please explain